# How can i standardize time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working on OHLC trading data and i have different datasets with different ranges of prices. For example, on one dataset the price will range from 100 to 150, on another from 2 to 3, on another from 0.5 to 0.8 and so on, so very different magnitudes.

On each dataset, i'm looping through the data and for each point i'm computing the slope on the last five prices on each point, and for that i'm using `np.polyfit()`.

Here is my code:

```
x = df['Date'].to_numpy()
y = df['Close'].to_numpy()

fits = []

for idx, j in enumerate(y):
    arr_y = y[:idx]
    arr_x = x[:idx]

    p_y = arr_y[-5:]
    p_x = arr_x[-5:]

    if len(py) >= 4 and len(px) >= 4:
        fit = np.polyfit(p_x, p_y, 1)
    
        ang_coeff = fit[0]
        intercept = fit[1]

        fits.append(ang_coeff)
    else:
        fits.append(np.nan)

df['SLOPE'] = fits
```

Here is what the code does: loop through the prices, and for each price, calculate the slope based on the last five prices.

This code works well, but the problem is that, since i'm working with more dataset where prices are going to be a lot different on each dataset, it becomes hard for me to perform any kind of analysis. So a very high slope value on a dataset will be very low on another dataset. My question is: how can i standardize or normalize (i know they are two different things) this data? How can i process my slope values so that an "high" slope value on a dataset will be high on another dataset too?

Here is a sample of my outputs:

```
          Date              Close       Slope
2021-01-17 00:00:00  34031.098338   29.572362
2021-01-17 04:00:00  34034.475090   20.097445
2021-01-17 08:00:00  34034.982351    8.655060
2021-01-17 12:00:00  34044.665386    3.914707
2021-01-17 16:00:00  34049.372571    4.538112
2021-01-17 20:00:00  34059.458965    4.673876
2021-01-18 00:00:00  34063.656831    6.435797
2021-01-18 04:00:00  34070.819559    7.214254
2021-01-18 08:00:00  34086.331298    6.659261
2021-01-18 12:00:00  34099.272005    8.527805
2021-01-18 16:00:00  34099.560423   10.230055
2021-01-18 20:00:00  34106.109568   10.025963
2021-01-19 00:00:00  34110.932662    8.380914
2021-01-19 04:00:00  34122.312205    5.604029
2021-01-19 08:00:00  34134.855812    5.745264
2021-01-19 12:00:00  34162.275141    8.679342
2021-01-19 16:00:00  34190.550778   13.625430
2021-01-19 20:00:00  34211.505419   19.919917
2021-01-20 00:00:00  34222.969489   23.408140
2021-01-20 04:00:00  34237.699255   22.545763
2021-01-20 08:00:00  34240.094551   18.326694
2021-01-20 12:00:00  34239.827609   12.528138
2021-01-20 16:00:00  34239.900596    7.376944
2021-01-20 20:00:00  34246.295214    3.599057
2021-01-21 00:00:00  34248.790292    1.699797
2021-01-21 04:00:00  34251.656251    2.385909
2021-01-21 08:00:00  34211.135875    3.254698
2021-01-21 12:00:00  34150.903010   -5.216841
2021-01-21 16:00:00  34127.857586  -22.843883
2021-01-21 20:00:00  34072.463679  -34.261865
2021-01-22 00:00:00  34018.425804  -44.166343
2021-01-22 04:00:00  33974.399053  -46.385947
2021-01-22 08:00:00  33946.475779  -46.243970
2021-01-22 12:00:00  33929.852159  -46.082824
2021-01-22 16:00:00  33927.598892  -35.717306
2021-01-22 20:00:00  33918.627401  -22.620072
2021-01-23 00:00:00  33905.044709  -13.042019
2021-01-23 04:00:00  33894.973038   -9.408690
2021-01-23 08:00:00  33861.417022   -9.231243
```

And a different dataset:

```
          Date           Close         Slope 
2021-02-18 04:00:00   0.492204  4.013722e-04
2021-02-18 08:00:00   0.492488  4.721365e-04
2021-02-18 12:00:00   0.493027  4.831912e-04
2021-02-18 16:00:00   0.493569  4.591663e-04
2021-02-18 20:00:00   0.494286  4.463141e-04
2021-02-19 00:00:00   0.494799  5.245110e-04
2021-02-19 04:00:00   0.495515  5.880476e-04
2021-02-19 08:00:00   0.496172  6.204948e-04
2021-02-19 12:00:00   0.496634  6.435782e-04
2021-02-19 16:00:00   0.497133  6.069365e-04
2021-02-19 20:00:00   0.497526  5.787601e-04
2021-02-20 00:00:00   0.497712  4.983345e-04
2021-02-20 04:00:00   0.497762  3.972312e-04
2021-02-20 08:00:00   0.497956  2.835458e-04
2021-02-20 12:00:00   0.498307  1.880521e-04
2021-02-20 16:00:00   0.498692  1.804976e-04
2021-02-20 20:00:00   0.498813  2.505608e-04
2021-02-21 00:00:00   0.499153  2.839021e-04
2021-02-21 04:00:00   0.499364  2.901245e-04
2021-02-21 08:00:00   0.499471  2.574213e-04
2021-02-21 12:00:00   0.499556  2.107408e-04
2021-02-21 16:00:00   0.499902  1.803125e-04
2021-02-21 20:00:00   0.500177  1.690260e-04
2021-02-22 00:00:00   0.500221  2.059057e-04
2021-02-22 04:00:00   0.501403  2.121462e-04
2021-02-22 08:00:00   0.502194  4.012434e-04
2021-02-22 12:00:00   0.502318  5.809102e-04
2021-02-22 16:00:00   0.502852  6.255775e-04
2021-02-22 20:00:00   0.503182  6.177676e-04
2021-02-23 00:00:00   0.503209  4.214821e-04
2021-02-23 04:00:00   0.503271  2.893487e-04
2021-02-23 08:00:00   0.502459  2.262497e-04
2021-02-23 12:00:00   0.502190 -6.951268e-05
2021-02-23 16:00:00   0.501697 -2.733434e-04
2021-02-23 20:00:00   0.501526 -4.105911e-04
2021-02-24 00:00:00   0.501506 -4.251799e-04
2021-02-24 04:00:00   0.501420 -2.571382e-04
2021-02-24 08:00:00   0.501332 -1.730550e-04
2021-02-24 12:00:00   0.501099 -8.359633e-05
2021-02-24 16:00:00   0.500684 -1.027447e-04
2021-02-24 20:00:00   0.500341 -1.962963e-04
2021-02-25 00:00:00   0.500027 -2.806065e-04
2021-02-25 04:00:00   0.499747 -3.368647e-04
2021-02-25 08:00:00   0.499428 -3.361539e-04
2021-02-25 12:00:00   0.499212 -3.105732e-04
2021-02-25 16:00:00   0.498883 -2.857117e-04
```

So these two datasets have very different `Close` values, which means the slope values are going to be completely different, so a very "high" slope value on the second dataset is nothing compared to the first dataset's slope values. Is there any way i can solve this? Do i have to apply some sort of normalization or standardization? Or do i need to use a different kind of calculation or metric? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `Close` values can be scaled using sklearn's [**`MinMaxScaler()`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)
2. You can also simplify the `polyfit` loop by using [**`Rolling.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) with a window size of 5

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

for df in [df1, df2]:
    df['Close'] = scaler.fit_transform(df['Close'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
    df['Slope'] = df['Close'].rolling(5, center=True).apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(x.index, x, 1)[0])
```

```py
>>> df1
                  Date     Close     Slope
0  2021-01-17 00:00:00  0.434814       NaN
1  2021-01-17 04:00:00  0.443467       NaN
2  2021-01-17 08:00:00  0.444766  0.011977
3  2021-01-17 12:00:00  0.469580  0.016492
4  2021-01-17 16:00:00  0.481642  0.018487
...
34 2021-01-22 16:00:00  0.169593 -0.024110
35 2021-01-22 20:00:00  0.146603 -0.023655
36 2021-01-23 00:00:00  0.111797 -0.039980
37 2021-01-23 04:00:00  0.085988       NaN
38 2021-01-23 08:00:00  0.000000       NaN
```

```py
>>> df2
                  Date     Close     Slope
0  2021-02-18 04:00:00  0.000000       NaN
1  2021-02-18 08:00:00  0.025662       NaN
2  2021-02-18 12:00:00  0.074365  0.047393
3  2021-02-18 16:00:00  0.123340  0.053140
4  2021-02-18 20:00:00  0.188127  0.056077
...
41 2021-02-25 00:00:00  0.706876 -0.028065
42 2021-02-25 04:00:00  0.681576 -0.025815
43 2021-02-25 08:00:00  0.652751 -0.025508
44 2021-02-25 12:00:00  0.633234       NaN
45 2021-02-25 16:00:00  0.603506       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Using MinMax scaler might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you adjust the scale by first calculating the Average True Range (ATR see https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/atr.asp) of one of the datasets and figure a reasonable scale to get a representative slope for that one. Then for other datasets calculate the ratio of their ATR to the standardized dataset and adjust the slope by that ratio.

For example if a new dataset has an ATR which is only a tenth of your "standard" ATR, then you multiply its slope measurements by 10 to put it to the same scale.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But in this case, how is using the ATR different from using Close prices? i mean, isn't the ATR too influenced by the price's magnitude? In this case, one ATR will be values between 100 and 500, the other mostly between 0 and 0.10 or so

Comment: Well the ATR should be based on more than just your last five candles in order to get a more generalized idea of the scale of the particular instrument. --just to clarify we are talking the same ohlc candle granularity (e.g. all one hour candles or all day candles etc) right? Anyway I thought your goal was to get particular slopes while adjusting for the differences that different instruments had in general over their larger history. If I am wrong then my answer is probably not a good one.

Comment: @Allaire Yes, in this case I'm using a 4H timeframe. My goal is to calculate the slope of the close and of moving averages at any point, I'm trying to get the inclination at each point of the chart, if it makes sense. Literally what I'm trying to get is, at each point, is the line going up or down and how much? I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: @JayK23 Ok, so if you are trading stocks (with 8 hour trading days) then your 4 hour candles are more or less half days. For forex they would only be a bout a fifth of a day. So the traditional 14 day ATR would be about 14 times longer a period than your last 5 candles in forex, but only about six times longer in stocks. So maybe use 30 day ATR if its stocks and 14 if its forex.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use **unit length scaling** (scaling to unit length) or **unit normal scaling** (standardization) if you want the series' to maintain their statistical properties but be scale free. It doesn't matter which one you use since you're just looking at slopes, and the fitted slopes between the two methods are identical (Montgomery, et. al., section 3.9).

Essentially, take the z-score of all of your regressors and the response variable, for UNS, and fit the transformed data without an intercept. For ULS, take the mean deviated regressor and response values divided by the square root of the corrected sum of squares values.

There are other methods you can try. They fall under the heading of *Feature Scaling*, and include **min-max normalization** and **mean normalization** [Wikipedia, 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling).

Montgomery, D. C., Peck, E. A., & Vining, G. G. (2012). Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis (5th ed.). John Wiley & Sons, Inc.